# Is it possible to have deep links open in the mobile app when installed rather than going to AMP pages?

Tags: google, google-search, amp, deeplinks

We have both app indexed deep linking + amp pages support for one of the product on our websites.
Initially the flow was that if a user has app installed the link used to take user to app and if app is not installed it used to show AMP page and flow is taken control by AMP app.

But recently even though user has app installed, it is shown AMP and flow goes in AMP funnel.
Do we have control of taking the user to desired funnel. Example our native app funnels perform better than AMP funnel. So we want the behavior is discussed above (native  > amp)

And is this AMP > native behaviour happened recently or announced somewhere or our app is a part of some kind of A/B Google is doing.

Comment: Personally I hate it when a link opens the app.   I find that a responsive mobile website is generally better than an app.   Facebook's mobile site is better than their app.   StackExchange's mobile site is better than their app.   Apps tend to lack features and not get updated often.   Just have users use the mobile website and focus on keeping it functioning well.

Comment: yes, but this totally depends on business to business & product. in our case we add much for value for a user on app than on mweb.